# Rotate an image in clockwise & Anti Clockwise direction

Tags: php, javascript, html, image-rotation, rotateanimation

I have used http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html raphel's script but. How how can v save this rotated image.

Answer (score 0):

It's an SVG, not really an image per-se.

You'll have to save the generated SVG via AJAX onto your server and render it with an external SVG-rendering library.

You could try `librsvg2-bin`, as I've heard that it works.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned it's an SVG element and it uses a source image to change it's angle upon clicking the rotate buttons. By inspecting the rotated image you'll see the SVG element like:

`<image x="160" y="120" width="320" height="240" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="http://raphaeljs.com/bd.jpg" transform="rotate(-90, 320, 240)"/>`

You'll notice that there's a `tranform` attribute that contains the `rotate(angle, x, y)` function. If you can find a way to get that angle value you can use it to manipulate the image source to generate a new image using PHP by using the [imagerotate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) function.

By doing this I got the `transform` attribute value:

`document.getElementById('holder').getElementsByTagName('image')[0].getAttribute('transform')`

This returns `"rotate(-90, 320, 240)"`

Of course this is a hack ;p